# How to make a triangle with a nested for

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

I need to use a nested for loop in Java to make a triangle like this

```
********
 *******
  ******
   *****
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
```

Heres my code:

```
 for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
  {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
      System.out.print('#');
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I get a triangle but not the one i want. Instead, my triangle looks like this:

```
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: If you show your code, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: for(int row=8; row>0;row--)

Comment: for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
  {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
      System.out.print('#');
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    triangle(8);
  }

private static void triangle(int len)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        for (int k = len-j; k > 0; k--)
        {
            System.out.print('#');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
  {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
      System.out.print('#');
    }
    System.out.println("");
}I just need the spaces to come first

Comment: yep. Or you could use just one loop:         
        
        char[] c = new char[] {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'};
        
        for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(c);
            c[i]=' ';
         }
      }

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the outer loop to count the 8 rows.  The inner loop would output the *'s for each row.  The row count of the outer loop will tell you how many spaces to output versus *'s.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
int f=8;`
for (int i=f; i>0; i--){

    for (int k=0; k<f-i;k++){
    System.out.print(' ');
    }
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    System.out.print('*');
    }
    if(i-1!=0)System.out.println("");
 }
```

Your code was also producing an unnecessary line at the end of the triangle, this code takes care of that line and is capable of making the desired triangle.

I have tested it, see [here](https://ideone.com/vbMaEB).